# Is it OK to use the phrase to stay for a week?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to say: " I stayed there a week" or must one use the preposition for: "I stayed there for a week"?

Comment: Both are acceptable, but the former is colloquial.

Comment: This would be a good question at [ell.se].

Answer (score 5):

They are both acceptable and have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think "I stayed there a week" implies that the duration of your "staying there" is one week, while "I stayed there for one week" is the grammatically correct version.  Therefore I would think that though "I stayed there a week" is more colloquial, the two sentences arrive at the same end.  But that's only my two cents.

Comment: The phrase "stayed a week" is both older and more common than "stayed for a week"; I don't think the claim that "stayed for a week" is grammatically more correct holds water. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stayed+for+a+week%2Cstayed+a+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstayed%20for%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstayed%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0).